# Home button broken and Notification Center stuck

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ipod, notifications

my home button on my ipod touch 5th Gen has been broken for  while so I have been using assistive touch. Earlier on my notification centre got stuck half way down the lock screen, making my ipod completely unusable.

I tried turning it off but the notification centre is blocking the slider and obviously I can't restart it since my home button is broken. Has anyone got any solutions? It's an absolute nightmare!

Comment: Please confirm if the circular home button is the one that malfunctions. If it's the sleep/wake button we can close this as a duplicate of the other questions on how to restart a phone when that other button has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the sleep-wake button to shut down the iPhone.

When you restart it, the notification center should be freed, but you will clearly have issues using the device if you lose control over the assistive touch, so be sure to set up backups the first chance you can.

Comment: Beat me by seconds :D

Comment: @Behdad DRAT! :D

Comment: Besides, Phoebe didn't ask about iPhones ;)

Comment: Holding the sleep/wake button doesn't help if you can't access the slider to turn off the device.

Answer (score 0):

let your device power down then try recharging it, and then hopefully it should be usable once again.

Comment: How does this answer the question: how to power off the device?

Comment: Let the battery run down?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "solution" to anyone who's home button has completely fallen out to the point where you can see the metal that's inside. The home button is connected to a piece of copper which leads upwards and disappears behind the screen sort of. Having 100% battery and being really pissed off that I was going to have to wait (and already having a really beat up iPod) I did something that MAY NOT BE A SMART IDEA. It's very possible that the way I fixed it could've caused me to dislodge a section of the screen, crack my iPod even more, or hurt the gutting/computer chips inside the iPod. So if you place the iPod flat with the bottom facing you and you look upwards into the hole where the home button use to be you can see a piece of copper. If you stab around in there eventually with something (probably not wise to use a paper clip, might get shocked) you'll eventually hit something that will trigger the home button command. Hold your probing device against that area and hold the top button on the screen until your iPod shuts off completely. Reboot, problem solved. I know I have an iPod so it may be slightly different but I highly doubt it.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad suggestion... though it probably won't shock you...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I will just let the power to out and I will just turn it back on with the charger due to the fact that my home bottom button is broken. So this way when it shuts off I can rebuild the power so that the notifications and that whole bar situation is figured out.