# How do I FORCE restart a iPhone 4s with a broken sleep/wake button AND notification area stuck midway!

Tags: iphone, notifications

Here are the details

- MY iphone 4s have a broken sleep/wake button!

  - The notification area is stuck midway and I can't do anything!
  - **I have assistive touch**
  - I have iTunes
  - Phone have no passcode and I can use the Control Center and Siri

I need to **force** restart!

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried running the battery out?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220451/home-button-broken-and-notification-center-stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Siri can open apps, but Notification Center is still there?

I'd guess you could try connecting to iTunes, make a backup, and restore from that backup over iTunes. Or you could use iTunes to install an iOS update if you aren't on the latest software. That'd force a restart but it might be overkill. You could also try draining the battery.

If the sleep button is broken, doesn't that bother you that you have to just wait for the screen to shut when you're finished or want it off? Maybe it's time for an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to Assistive touch: hold the power off button and don't let go, your iPhone will first shut off and if you keep holding it the iPhone will turn back on.

Comment: What will holding the broken power button do?